# PAX Exam integration test REST client call to REST service fails with Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: rest, osgi, cxf, apache-servicemix, pax-exam

I have an integration test that injects a rest client into the test class. When that rest client calls a rest service being hosted by the same pax exam test container everything stops for about a minute until I get a long list of Socket Read Timeout exceptions and connection refused exceptions. If I inject a rest client that calls a rest service in another container everything works fine. It almost seems like the rest service isn't given a thread to execute in. If I start up the pax exam container manually I can verify that the rest service has started correctly. And if I inject the OSGi service into the test class everything works correctly.  Using PaxExam 3.6 and Apache ServiceMix (4.5.3)

Stack Trace:

```
2015-04-22 17:10:02,211 | WARN  | ion(1)-127.0.0.1 | PhaseInterceptorChain            | 123 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-api - 2.6.6 | Interceptor for {http://rest.mediation.velocity.randomness.com/}mediationService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:530)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:205)[139:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:2.6.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.getmediations(Unknown Source)
    at com.randomness.velocity.mediation.rest.client.mediationClient.getmediations(mediationClient.java:90)[282:mediation-rest-client:3.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.randomness.velocity.mediation.rest.client.mediationClient.getmediations(mediationClient.java:97)[282:mediation-rest-client:3.1.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.randomness.velocity.itest.client_management.DataCleanupTests.verifyvelocityClientManagementStarts(DataCleanupTests.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_75]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:67)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.ContainerTestRunner.runChild(ContainerTestRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)[313:org.ops4j.pax.tipi.junit:4.11.0.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.invokeViaJUnit(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:124)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:97)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_75]
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.internal.RemoteBundleContextImpl.remoteCall(RemoteBundleContextImpl.java:80)[311:org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc:3.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking https://127.0.0.1:7103/mediation/patient/ff8081814ce1299a014ce142cb410065?materialization=Full: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)[:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1469)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1454)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:659)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.6]
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)[:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)[:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1440)[135:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.  I added an osgi:service to a spring config in the integration test project that exposed the rest client as an osgi service so I could inject the client into the test class.  By doing that I created a second service in the osgi container that was advertised via the same interface that the rest service was using to look up the real osgi service implementation.  So the rest service was actually getting the rest client injected into it instead of the osgi service impl, this created an infinite loop that finally crashed out and threw tons of connection refused and socket read timeout exceptions to my console.  Good stuff